# Can anyone please explain usage of few settings in my Dlink Adsl modem+router?

Tags: networking, router, lan, dhcp, vlan

The router is Dlink 2730U. The documentation doesn't list the usage and function.

1. DHCP server settings list both Lan and wan ports... please see pic

[image]

Not sure, how WAN ports are used in DHCP? Better to uncheck WAN ports for better security?

2. LAN Port VLAN settings .. not sure what they are for.. Can this be used to create a VLAN for individual LAN ports for better security? If so, please let me know how to configure that. pic below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the **WLAN** ports for better security yes, this means that no one can access your router from the air, if you disable the **WAN** port though, you lose all internet connection on your router, because the WAN port is the cable you plug in to the router for internet. (its often a big yellow or blue one)

VLAN's are used for more security yes, you can put different LAN ports in different VLAN's so that they cannot interact with each other in ANY way. unless you have a trunk, this is a port that can access ANY VLAN at will.

A side note: it is kinda weird that you have "WLAN Ports", the WLAN should just be a device that transmits and recieves data.

I hope I answered your question!

Comment: I know, that was what i meant :)
Disabling WLAN is disabling WiFi
Disabling WAN is disabling internet input
Disabling LAN is disabling Ethernet port
And to tell you how to configure VLAN's i would need hands on time with the router itself. But dont worry, you dont really need VLAN's in your home network.

Comment: Mixed up WLAN and WAN!. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: It happens.. ;P